# Java compare object of efficiency

Tags: java

In Java inside compare Hashcode  of  String Object and direct compare  String Object both Who is more efficient  and Why is that

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     String a = "Hello";
     String b="Hello";
     int i = a.hashCode();
     System.out.println(i);
     int v = b.hashCode();
     System.out.println(v);

     if (i==v){
        System.out.println("ture");
      }else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    }
```

Comment: You're comparing hashcodes in your example, but there is no alternative method of comparison.  What is the other method of comparison?

Comment: Two unequal object can have same hashcode

Comment: Your question has potential, please edit it and tell us what you mean by "efficiency". You probably want to know differences between hashcode and equals. There are plenty of those questions on StackOverflow. Research a little more and let us know how different this question is from others on this site.

Comment: the equal method and hashCode are not sure in the strong relationship especially when you overwrite one of them and forgot to overwrite the another. And the "efficiency" may depend on how you write the equal and the hashcode method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hashCode`s are a shortcut, not a real test of equality. Two objects that are equal should have the same hash code, but the opposite is not necessarily true. E.g., the strings `"BBAa"` and `"AaBB"` have the same hash code (at least with OpenJDK 8, they both are 2031744), but are definitely **not** equal.

Answer (score 0):

hashcode on String is buffererized the first computation can be long but it becomme shorter at the second call but equality and hashcode did'nt mean the same thing at all !

the only relationships between equality and hashcode equalityare these one :

different hashcode => unequality

equality => same hashcode

**those ones are COMPLETELY FALSE :**

same hashCode => equality

unequality => different hashcode